# Copying files from a folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file

I am developing a CMS with laravel at work, in case I publish the pages of a brand site, I need to create a folder structure before publishing.

In case I have
`app / themes / default / public` I want to copy the files inside the`public` folder and send them to this folder that is going to be created `app / websites-published / '. $ content-> nanoid`.

How would I do that?

```
    public function publish(Request $request, Site $site)
    {
        /** @var  $contents */
        $contents = $site->contents;

        /** @var  $content */
        foreach ($contents as $content) {

            // Copiar o Public do THEME - THEME/NOME DO TEMA/PUBLIC - WebsitePublished->Nanoid
            // Conteudo do ex: THEME/PUBLIC
            $copyTheme = storage_path('app/themes/default/public');
            $sendTheme = public_path('app/websites-published/' . $content->nanoid);
            copy($copyTheme, $sendTheme);


            // Copiar o Public do WEBSITE - WebsitePublished->Site:Nanoid
            // Conteudo do ex: WEBSITE/SUZUKI/PUBLIC


            // APP/WEBPUBLISHED
        }

        return $this->viewService->renderContent($request, $content);
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you show us? Does it error? Does it do anything? Does it do nothing? Go on... giz a clue

Comment: Did you run this code? What version of Laravel are you on?

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a Filesystem that can handle files operations on most of systems. The `Storage` facade class can only copy individual file, so you would need to loop to all of them easily, but this is too much work as the class `Filesystem` can copy or move entire directory recursively while creating the directories recursively.

To move a whole directory, you have to do import Filesystem class :

```
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
```

And use the `copyDirectory()` method :

```
public function publish(Request $request, Site $site)
{
    /** @var  $contents */
    $contents = $site->contents;

    /** @var  $content */
    foreach ($contents as $content) {

        // Copiar o Public do THEME - THEME/NOME DO TEMA/PUBLIC - WebsitePublished->Nanoid
        // Conteudo do ex: THEME/PUBLIC
        $copyTheme = storage_path('app/themes/default/public');
        $sendTheme = public_path('app/websites-published/' . $content->nanoid);
        $filesys = new Filesystem();
        $filesys->moveDirectory($copyTheme, $sendTheme);


        // Copiar o Public do WEBSITE - WebsitePublished->Site:Nanoid
        // Conteudo do ex: WEBSITE/SUZUKI/PUBLIC


        // APP/WEBPUBLISHED
    }

    return $this->viewService->renderContent($request, $content);
}
```